# How can I make a command synchronous when updating an object's state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6

I am developing a game engine. An angularjs front-end talks to an endpoint in a .NET WebAPI project running on IIS. This web api is a facade that just runs commands against the domain logic of the game which is in a separate project. I have a unit of work that is currently using entity framework.

So, angularjs code calls an endpoint in a webapi website on IIS which creates a command to run against the game. For example: open bank account.

This command would load the game's instance from the data store, check the completion and then execute the command to open the bank account. There are a lot of events that happen in the execute commands that change game instance data.

I have a lot of these commands that all have the same base class but only one is ever supposed to be called at once.

```
public abstract class GameInstanceCommandHandler<T>
    : CommandHandlerBase<T, GameInstanceIDCommandResult>
    where T : GameInstanceCommand
{
    protected GameInstance GameInstance { get; private set; }

    protected GameInstanceCommandHandler() { }

    public GameInstanceCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }

    public override GameInstanceIDCommandResult Execute(T command)
    {
        Check.Null(command, "command");

        GameInstance = UnitOfWork.GetGameInstance(command.GameInstanceID);

        if (GameInstance == null)
            return GetResult(false, "Could not find game instance.");

        if (GameInstance.IsComplete)
        {
            var completeResult = GetResult(GameInstance.ID);
            completeResult.Messages.Add("Game is complete, you cannot update the game state.");
            completeResult.Success = false;
            completeResult.IsGameComplete = true;
            return completeResult;
        }

        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance, p => p.AppInstances);

        var result = ExecuteCommand(command);

        UnitOfWork.Save();

        return result;
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(bool success, string message)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(success, message);
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(Guid id)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(id);
    }

    protected void LoadGameAndGameApps()
    {
        UnitOfWork.LoadReference(GameInstance, p => p.Game);
        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance.Game, p => p.GameApps);
    }

    protected abstract GameInstanceIDCommandResult ExecuteCommand(T command);
}
```

All base classes override the abstract ExecuteCommand. Everything runs fine, I can run my engine using a console project, or in IIS or where ever, it's fine.

The issue is when multiple commands want to change the game instance state at the same time. If I called a command to calculate the interest on a bankaccount in the game, currently 5 calls to the same command will create 5 calculations.

I want to make sure that only one command is allows to execute at a time for a given game instance. As this is a separate library and isn't just built for running in an IIS process I know that this concern should be handled in this file. I thought about updating the code to match below:

```
public abstract class GameInstanceCommandHandler<T>
    : CommandHandlerBase<T, GameInstanceIDCommandResult>
    where T : GameInstanceCommand
{
    private static readonly object @lock = new object();
    private static volatile List<Guid> GameInstanceIDs = new List<Guid>();

    protected GameInstance GameInstance { get; private set; }

    protected GameInstanceCommandHandler() { }

    public GameInstanceCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }

    public override GameInstanceIDCommandResult Execute(T command)
    {
        Check.Null(command, "command");

        lock(@lock)
        {
            // if game id is updating then return 
            if(GameInstanceIDs.Any(p => p == command.GameInstanceID))
                return GetResult(false, "The game is already being updated.");

            // (lock for update)
            GameInstanceIDs.Add(command.GameInstanceID);
        }

        try
        {
            GameInstance = UnitOfWork.GetGameInstance(command.GameInstanceID);

            if (GameInstance == null)
                return GetResult(false, "Could not find game instance.");

            if (GameInstance.IsComplete)
            {
                var completeResult = GetResult(GameInstance.ID);
                completeResult.Messages.Add("Game is complete, you cannot update the game state.");
                completeResult.Success = false;
                completeResult.IsGameComplete = true;
                return completeResult;
            }

            UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance, p => p.AppInstances);

            var result = ExecuteCommand(command);

            UnitOfWork.Save();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        finally
        {
            lock (@lock)
            {
                GameInstanceIDs.Remove(command.GameInstanceID);
            }
        }
        return GetResult(false, "There was an error.");
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(bool success, string message)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(success, message);
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(Guid id)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(id);
    }

    protected void LoadGameAndGameApps()
    {
        UnitOfWork.LoadReference(GameInstance, p => p.Game);
        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance.Game, p => p.GameApps);
    }

    protected abstract GameInstanceIDCommandResult ExecuteCommand(T command);
}
```

This fixes my issue completely but there are a number of issues.

1. Will this cause me headaches when I am running it in IIS?
2. If I want to load balance this library on many app servers then this won't work.
3. If there are a million game instances then the list will grow huge and performance will suffer.

The other fix is this by moving the lock to the database:

```
public abstract class GameInstanceCommandHandler<T>
    : CommandHandlerBase<T, GameInstanceIDCommandResult>
    where T : GameInstanceCommand
{
    private static readonly object @lock = new object();

    protected GameInstance GameInstance { get; private set; }

    protected GameInstanceCommandHandler() { }

    public GameInstanceCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }

    public override GameInstanceIDCommandResult Execute(T command)
    {
        Check.Null(command, "command");

        lock(@lock)
        {
            GameInstance = UnitOfWork.GetGameInstance(command.GameInstanceID);

            if (GameInstance == null)
                return GetResult(false, "Could not find game instance.");

            if(GameInstance.IsLocked)
                return GetResult(false, "Game is locked by another command.");

            // Lock the game in the database or datastore
            GameInstance.Lock();
            UnitOfWork.Save();

            // Unlock only local copy
            GameInstance.UnLock();
        }

        try
        {
            if (GameInstance.IsComplete)
            {
                var completeResult = GetResult(GameInstance.ID);
                completeResult.Messages.Add("Game is complete, you cannot update the game state.");
                completeResult.Success = false;
                completeResult.IsGameComplete = true;
                return completeResult;
            }

            UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance, p => p.AppInstances);

            var result = ExecuteCommand(command);
            // this will unlock the gameinstance on the save
            UnitOfWork.Save();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        return GetResult(false, "There was an error.");
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(bool success, string message)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(success, message);
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(Guid id)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(id);
    }

    protected void LoadGameAndGameApps()
    {
        UnitOfWork.LoadReference(GameInstance, p => p.Game);
        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance.Game, p => p.GameApps);
    }

    protected abstract GameInstanceIDCommandResult ExecuteCommand(T command);
}
```

Perhaps I am thinking about this the wrong way. Any help would be great.

Comment: You should put the GameInstance.Lock(); UnitOfWork.Save(); inside try block and GameInstance.UnLock(); inside finally block. So in case of any exception suring Save, the lock will be released for sure.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Thanks for that, yes I will put some try catches around. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided that the best way currently is to have a queue of IDs. I try to immediately enter the game instance id and if the insert is OK then continue. After doing work remove the id from the list. If the id insert fails then it already exists.

This fix is pretty much the same as the lock but I am relying on a unique key value store. I am probably going to create an interface and class that handles this so if the database fails I can store the failures in a file or someplace else to make sure to clear out the ids later.

I am definitely up for more suggestions to this as it really has a bad code smell.

```
public abstract class GameInstanceCommandHandler<T>
    : CommandHandlerBase<T, GameInstanceIDCommandResult>
    where T : GameInstanceCommand
{
    protected GameInstance GameInstance { get; private set; }

    protected GameInstanceCommandHandler() { }

    public GameInstanceCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow)
    {
    }

    public override GameInstanceIDCommandResult Execute(T command)
    {
        Check.Null(command, "command");

        try
        {
            AddCommandInstance(command.GameInstanceID);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return GetResult(false, "Only one command can be ran on an instance at a time.");
        }

        GameInstance = UnitOfWork.GameInstances.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == command.GameInstanceID);

        if (GameInstance == null)
        {
            RemoveCommandInstance(command.GameInstanceID);
            return GetResult(false, "Could not find game instance.");
        }

        if (GameInstance.IsComplete)
        {
            var completeResult = GetResult(GameInstance.ID);
            completeResult.Messages.Add("Game is complete, you cannot update the game state.");
            completeResult.Success = false;
            completeResult.IsGameComplete = true;
            RemoveCommandInstance(command.GameInstanceID);
            return completeResult;
        }

        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance, p => p.AppInstances);

        GameInstanceIDCommandResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = ExecuteCommand(command);
            UnitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = GetResult(false, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            RemoveCommandInstance(command.GameInstanceID);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void AddCommandInstance(Guid gameInstanceID)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Add(new CommandInstance() { ID = gameInstanceID });
        UnitOfWork.Save();
    }

    private void RemoveCommandInstance(Guid gameInstanceID)
    {
        UnitOfWork.Remove(UnitOfWork.CommandInstances.First(p => p.ID == gameInstanceID));
        UnitOfWork.Save();
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(bool success, string message)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(success, message);
    }

    protected GameInstanceIDCommandResult GetResult(Guid id)
    {
        return new GameInstanceIDCommandResult(id);
    }

    protected void LoadGameAndGameApps()
    {
        UnitOfWork.LoadReference(GameInstance, p => p.Game);
        UnitOfWork.LoadCollection(GameInstance.Game, p => p.GameApps);
    }

    protected abstract GameInstanceIDCommandResult ExecuteCommand(T command);
}
```

Comment: What I was thinking- you can try executing the lock block in a separate thread, independently. It might impact the shared resources but there are ways to take care of that. So this would keep the mail thread free, each time a new thread will be working independently. You might have to create a thread pool as well.